# Prevent Initial Animation in Flutter Go Router (go_router)

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I have set up some routes with [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router)  inside a `LayoutBuilder`. This is so I can resize my app on desktop and change the UI depending on the space available.

Here's a simplified view of my app:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Routes(),
        ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Then here are my routes:

```dart
class Routes extends StatelessWidget {
  Routes({super.key});

  final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    initialLocation: '/',
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: const Master(),
          );
        },
      ),
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that there is an initial animation for the router. When you **hot restart** or **resize the window** and trigger the `LayoutBuilder`, it rebuilds the `Routes` widget. This is fine, but the initial animation gets triggered multiple times and looks jarring. [Here's a screen recording to show what I mean](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4glvv3kp99vi52jkuqljs/GoRouter.mov?rlkey=2rsruvkqi3z654plghyulnccu&dl=0).

How do I disable this initial `go_router` animation so the app stays still while the window is being resized?

Comment: I am used to creating wrapper for each route

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: Using LayoutBuilder for each page(Scaffold) instead of top level.

Comment: Oh! That's an excellent idea. I'll try it...